# Como pegar as referências do objeto em vb.net ou c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Tenho o código a seguir:

```
Dim objeto1 as new ClasseTal
Dim objeto2 as new SubClasse
Dim objeto3 as new SubClasse

objeto2.Prop1 = objeto1

objeto3.Prop1 = objeto1
```

ou seja, quero contar o número de referênciação do `objeto1`, neste caso teria que ser 2, pois está no `objeto2` e no `objeto3`.

Comment: O CLR não mantém maiores contagens de referência, portanto, não há contagem de referência para ser obtida. O coletor de lixo só se importa se um objeto tem referências zero ou pelo menos uma referência.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100811-00/?p=13173/

Comment: Talvez você possa criar alguma variável, algum campo estático que conte cada vez que a classe for instanciada.

Comment: Talvez a forma mais simples de resolver a questão seria colocar um contador estático (de acesso global) que seria incrementado no construtor da classe. Basicamente, sempre que a classe fosse instanciada o contador aumentava.

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu saiba o .NET não te informa a quantidade de referencias que um objeto possui programaticamente, já que é função do GC gerenciar as referencias. 
Pesquisando um pouco descobri este tópico: [C# - Get number of references to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686416/c-sharp-get-number-of-references-to-object)

Nele um usuário diz que a contagem das referencias pode ser perigoso pois pode existir casos de referencia circular.

Más você também pode construir um "Gerenciador" que conte a quantidade de referencias usando o [WeakReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)
 e um dicionario.
Segue um exemplo básico para ter uma noção. (Pode haver erro de lógica)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace HelperStack
{
    public static class ContadorHelper
    {

        /*
         * var objeto1 as new ClasseTal
         * var objeto2 as new SubClasse
         * var objeto3 as new SubClasse
         *
         * objeto2.Prop1 = objeto1.ObterReferencia()
         *
         * objeto3.Prop1 = objeto1.ObterReferencia()
         * Console.log(objeto1.ObterContador())
         */
        private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<WeakReference, int>> Referencias { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<WeakReference, int>>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Use esta função toda vez que quiser usar a referencia do objeto em outro local
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Objeto qualquer.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static object ObterReferencia(this object obj)
        {
            AtualizarLista();

            if (Referencias.Count(x => x.Key == obj.GetHashCode()) > 0)
            {
                var aux = Referencias[obj.GetHashCode()].FirstOrDefault();
                if (aux.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<WeakReference, int>)))
                {
                    //Retorna uma unica referencia
                    Referencias[obj.GetHashCode()].Add(new WeakReference(obj), 1);
                    return obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    Referencias[obj.GetHashCode()][aux.Key] = aux.Value + 1;
                    //Retorna uma referencia do objeto
                    return aux.Key.Target;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Cria uma nova estrutura
                Referencias.Add(obj.GetHashCode(), new Dictionary<WeakReference, int>());
                Referencias[obj.GetHashCode()].Add(new WeakReference(obj), 1);
                return obj;
            }
        }
        public static int ObterContador(this object obj)
        {
            AtualizarLista();

            if (Referencias.Count(x => x.Key == obj.GetHashCode()) > 0)
            {
                //Obtem a quantodade 
                return Referencias[obj.GetHashCode()].First().Value;
            }
            else
            {
                //Caso não exista referencia do objeto
                return -1;
            }
        }
        private static void AtualizarLista()
        {
            List<int> remover = new List<int>();
            foreach (var objRef in Referencias)
            {
                //Verifica se o GC coletou o objeto
                if (objRef.Value.First().Key.IsAlive)
                {
                    remover.Add(objRef.Key);
                }
            }

            foreach (var keys in remover)
            {
                Referencias.Remove(keys);
            }
        }
    }
}
```